# Bases stream-video concepts (from NodeJS to MediaSource)

Tags: node.js, video, video-streaming, media-source

I'm searching for a solution in streaming viedo from NodeJS server to client, and then merge them with MediaStream API.

The point is that I don't know how streaming really works.

How I have to send the video chunks throughout HTTP protocol? I see the status code 206 that is 'Partial Content'. I think that chunks generate lots of 206 code, and the last chunk generate 200 code like this:

```
chunck 1/5 --> 206 'Partial Content'
chunck 2/5 --> 206 'Partial Content'
chunck 3/5 --> 206 'Partial Content'
chunck 4/5 --> 206 'Partial Content'
chunck 5/5 --> 200 'OK'
```

That's right?

---

### Server Side

I found lots of example where is use the file path to generate the chunk, but I have a Buffer with the binary of the video, how I can generate the chunk?

---

### Client Side

I see that there's not a well done documentation about MediaSource API. In the examples that I found in the web is used the `webkitsourceopen`or `sourceopen` event, but I don't understand when they are call.

---

Someone can explain  me something more about streaming video, and even fix my doubts about server and client code?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: its a greate question